# How to add text on a image in html5 and css3

Tags: html, css

Enclosing the code and how can i add the text on image  how write the code for it.as im working on it

```
<div class="content">
                <div class="section">
                <div class="box">
                    <a href="#">

                    <img src="./images/pc.jpg" alt style="height: 210px; width: 215px; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: -13px; border-bottom: 10px solid blue;"></a> 


                    <a href="#"><img src="./images/pc.jpg" style="height: 210px; width: 215px; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: 25px;border-bottom: 10px solid blue;"></a> 

                    <a href="#"><img src="./images/pc.jpg" style="height: 210px; width: 215px; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: 25px;border-bottom: 10px solid blue;"></a> 
                    <br>
                    <a href="#"><img src="./images/pc.jpg" style="height: 210px; width: 215px; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: -13px;border-bottom: 10px solid blue;"></a> 

                    <a href="#"><img src="./images/pc.jpg" style="height: 210px; width: 215px; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: 25px;border-bottom: 10px solid blue;"></a> 

                    <a href="#"><img src="./images/pc.jpg" style="height: 210px; width: 215px; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: 25px;border-bottom: 10px solid blue;"></a> 

                </div>

                </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: can you be more specific ? what text ? there are a number of ways to do it. first thing that comes to mind is using `position` ( absolute and relative ) but you need to share the relevant HTML ( text also ) and CSS styles you have tried to achieve this.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cu8kbxau/ is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following: https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Answer (score 0):

Three steps:

1. Give the `div` a `position: relative`
2. Set the image as a `background-image` of the `div`
3. Give the text inside the `div` a `position: absolute` so you can position it wherever you need to

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
position: relative;
background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/340/180');
width: 340px;
height: 180px;
}

div p {
position: absolute;
top: 108px;
right: 6px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 36px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 4px 12px;
border-radius: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>I am a little kitten</p>
</div>
```